# how to create log files for test execution

Tags: python, automation, logging

I am trying to create a testcontroller and wants the execution of tests to be collected a a file.

i know using, tee and redirecting the test script execution to a certain file, but I am interested to do it with python over linux.

So, in this case whenever a test is executed the log file should get created, and all the execution logs including stdin,stdout and stderr should get collected to this file.

Requesting some body to suggest me, how to implement this kind of idea!

Thanks
OpenFile

Comment: If you don't want to "re-invent the wheel" There are [existing frameworks](http://code.google.com/p/pycopia/) that already do that, and more (shameless plug).

Answer (score 5):

There are several good logging modules, starting with the built-in `logging`, here is the [official cookbook](http://docs.python.org/dev/howto/logging-cookbook.html). Among the more interesting 3rd party libraries is [Logbook](http://packages.python.org/Logbook/index.html), here is a pretty bare example just scratching the surface of its [very cool features](http://thechangelog.com/post/1084635183/logbook-impressive-logging-for-python):

```
import logbook

def f(i,j):
    return i+j

logger = logbook.Logger('my application logger')
log = logbook.FileHandler('so.log')
log.push_application()

try:
    f(1, '2')
    logger.info('called '+f.__name__)
except:
    logger.warn('failed on ')


try:
    f(1, 2)
    logger.info('called '+f.__name__)
except:
    logger.warn('choked on, ')
```

`so.log` then looks like this:

```
[2011-05-19 07:40] WARNING: my application logger: failed on
[2011-05-19 07:40] INFO: my application logger: called f
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
import sys

# Save the current stream
save_out = sys.stdout

# Define the log file
f = "a_log_file.log"
# Append to existing log file. 
# Change 'a' to 'w' to recreate the log file each time.
fsock = open(f, 'a')

# Set stream to file
sys.stdout = fsock

###
# do something here 
# any print function calls will send the stream to file f
###

# Reset back the stream to what it was
# any print function calls will send the stream to the previous stream
sys.stdout = save_out
fsock.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

Open and write to a file:

```
mylogfile = 'bla.log'
f = open(mylogfile, 'a')
f.write('i am logging! logging logging!....loggin? timber!....')
f.close()
```

## look in root direct of script for 'bla.log' and read, enjoy

Comment: It's overwriting the file, if you open it with 'w'.

Answer (score 2):

You can write a function like this:

```
def writeInLog(msg):
    with open("log", "a") as f:
        f.write(msg+"\n")
```

It will open the file "*log*", and append ("*a*") the message followed by a newline, then close the file.

Answer (score 0):

```
# Save the current stream
saveout = sys.stdout


f = "a_log_file.log"
fsock = open(f, 'w')

# Set stream to file
sys.stdout = fsock

###
# do something here 
# any print function will send the stream to file f
###

# Reset back the stream to what it was
sys.stdout = saveout
fsock.close()
```